# How to remove a specific mounted HD from the desktop when its not mounted in /media ? 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive, icons, fstab

I added a hard-disk and mounted it via fstab as my download folder. 
Works well except it still shows up on the desktop.

But it isn't mounted in the /media folder. How do I remove a mounted volume icon from the Desktop without editing gconf or using ubuntu tweaks and disabling all (USB etc.) mounted volume desktop icons?

[image]